# typeerror '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, csv, python-2.6

When I try to open a file in python I get the error, typeerror '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable. The code is as below, can someone kindly help me please

```
with open(file) as f:  
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')  
    for line in reader:  
        oldseq, city, state, newseq = line
```

The error is here,  in the following code,  for line in reader[:1]:

```
with open(newfile) as f:  
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')  
    for line in reader[:1]:  
        oldseq, city, state, newseq = line
```

I need to just skip the first line as it has headers, thats why I was doing reader[:1]

Comment: If you show us the *full* traceback, we most likely can help you find where the real problem is occurring. It is not in the code you posted.

Comment: I just updated the code & now Im pointing to the error, can you please help

Comment: You are trying to skip the header of the CSV file. Slicing doesn't work, use `reader.next()` instead to skip the first row.

Comment: How about reader(next) would that work?

Comment: Oops, I see now that `next()` was added in 2.6 already.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot slice a `reader` object; you can *skip* the first row with:

```
with open(newfile) as f:  
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    next(reader, None)  # skip header
    for line in reader:  
        oldseq, city, state, newseq = line
```

Comment: Can you please explain the initial try command?

Comment: @user1345260: Actually, I was wrong, the [`next()` builtin](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) was added in 2.6 already. The `try` tests if the name exists, in Python 2.5 trying to access `next` will rase a `NameError` and the `except` block then defines a Python-only implementation that does the same thing as the built-in.

Comment: @user1345260: But I removed it, it is redundant here, and your question is really a dupe.

Comment: And shouldn't I remove [:1] from the line for line in reader[:1]:

Comment: Yes. `+++ OUT OF CAFFIENE ERROR +++ REDO FROM START +++` (e.g. my mistake, sorry)

Comment: At the line next(reader, None)  it says typeerror dict object is not callable

Comment: @user1345260: Then you already used `next` for a dictionary object in your local code. Use `del next` to get rid of that dictionary, or rename it in your script.